# What is a non-physical meaning of "total burn"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> I had seen the NIN video they had out then that looked like a **total burn** of a Joel-Peter Witkin photo.

What does *total burn* mean here?  It doesn't seem to have the physical meaning of *burn*.

Comment: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=burn) can sometimes be helpful in contexts like these.

Comment: @SamuelLijin sorry, but I looked up there and I didn't find any appropriate meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Burn* is this sense means an insult of some kind, especially if it's a witty retort.

*Total* is used as an intensifier.

This instance is a slightly broader use than normal where it seems to be used in place of *parody*.